# How to make PyQt5 wait n seconds before returning page

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to scrape a webpage using the following PyQt5 function by passing the url into the function as a parameter. the function returns the page data:

```
def get_html(url):
    class Render(QWebEngineView):
        def __init__(self, url):
            self.html = None
            self.app = APP.instance()
            QWebEngineView.__init__(self)
            self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
            self.load(QUrl(url))

            while self.html is None:
                self.app.processEvents(QEventLoop.ExcludeUserInputEvents | QEventLoop.ExcludeSocketNotifiers | QEventLoop.WaitForMoreEvents)
            self.app.quit()

        def _callable(self, data):
            self.html = data

        def _loadFinished(self, result):
            self.page().toHtml(self._callable)

    return Render(url).html
```

but the program faces a cloudflare error for unknown reasons to me, and it needs a couple of seconds to load the page properly. So how can I make the function wait for n seconds to fully load the page before proceeding to return the page data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly invoking toHtml you should use a QTimer:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage


APP = QApplication.instance()
if APP is None:
    APP = QApplication([])


class PageHelper(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url, timeout=0):
        self.html = ""
        self.timeout = timeout
        app = APP.instance()
        super().__init__()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.handle_load_finished)

        self.load(QUrl.fromUserInput(url))

        app.exec_()

    def handle_load_finished(self, ok):
        if ok:
            QTimer.singleShot(self.timeout * 1000, self.to_html)
        else:
            QApplication.quit()

    def to_html(self):
        self.toHtml(self._html_callable)

    def _html_callable(self, html):
        self.html = html
        QApplication.quit()


def get_html(url, timeout=0):
    page = PageHelper(url, timeout)
    return page.html


print(get_html("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68854582", timeout=5))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I implemented your solution but got the error: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: @Mahdi_J How strange, you could run the script from the console/CMD: `python /path/od/script.py` so that you can give me more precise information about the error,

Comment: I ran the code with from the console and this is the error that i got:
QCoreApplication::arguments: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
QCoreApplication::arguments: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath: Please instantiate the QApplication object first

Comment: @Mahdi_J Are you using just my script or have you added more code?

Comment: my mistake, I had some other code in the script. I reran the code in a seperate script and it worked fine, but I still got the cloudflare error in the page string. What part of the code should I edit for the code to wait for some seconds?

Comment: @Mahdi_J I don't know what you mean, it seems you have an XY problem. Your question from your post is to delay and that's what my code does. I recommend you create a **new post** where you show the error message in addition to the url you indicate

Comment: I just want to increase the amount of delay. should I modify the timeout value or the singleshot method parameters?

Comment: @Mahdi_J I do not know what you mean, I do not know the page you want to download the html. Without more information it is difficult to help you. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding. this is the page I want to load, if you have time, please see if you can load the page properly with your solution.: ```www.ramzinex.com```

Comment: @Mahdi_J Create a new post and report the problem you have with that page so that the community can help you

Comment: @Mahdi_J try with this code: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/83c283ef31c3250f0bc3f87362f53722

Comment: thank you. I did. It outputs these values (each in a new line) and then just freezes without completing the process: 0 100 0 100 False